# MongoDB : $hour operator does not accept an object as an operand

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm experiencing trouble trying to get the HOUR from a collection and subtracting 3 hours (GMT-3)

if I run

```
   db.post.aggregate(
   [{$match : {'uri' : /fantastic/ }   },
     {
       $project:
         {
           _id: 0,
           created_at : 1,
           date_minus_3 : {$subtract:["$created_at",3*60*60*1000]},
           hour_from_original: { $hour: "$created_at" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

I get

```
(...)
    {
        "created_at" : ISODate("2014-06-03T02:51:42.000Z"),
        "date_minus_3" : ISODate("2014-06-02T23:51:42.000Z"),
        "hour_from_original" : 2
    }, 
(...)
```

but if I what to get the hour from the "date_minus_3"

```
   db.post.aggregate(
   [{$match : {'uri' : /fantastic/ }   },
     {
       $project:
         {
           _id: 0,
           created_at : 1,
           date_minus_3 : {$subtract:["$created_at",3*60*60*1000]},
           hour_from_original: { $hour: "$created_at" },
           hour_from_date_minus_3 : {$hour: {$subtract:["$created_at",3*60*60*1000]}}
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

I get an error message

```
    Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
([object Array])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):10

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
  "errmsg" : "exception: the $hour operator does not accept an object as an operand",
  "code" : 16021,
  "ok" : 0
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: It works fine for me with MongoDB 3.0.2. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have two separate **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** pipelines where you calculate the field with the date minus three hours with the first **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** pipeline stage and then the next pipeline step then applies the [**`$hour`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) operator on to the new minus 3 hours date.

Suppose you have the following test documents inserted for testing purposes:

```
db.test.insert([
    {"created_at" : ISODate("2014-06-03T02:51:42.000Z")},
    {"created_at" : ISODate("2014-06-04T11:23:17.000Z")}
])
```

The above aggregation pipeline that gives you the hour part from the date minus three should follow:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
       $project:
         {
           _id: 0,
           created_at : 1,
           date_minus_3 : {$subtract:["$created_at",3*60*60*1000]},
           hour_from_original: { $hour: "$created_at" }
         }
     },
     {
       $project:
         {
           _id: 0,
           created_at : 1,
           date_minus_3 : 1,
           hour_from_original: 1,
           hour_from_date_minus_3 : { $hour: "$date_minus_3" }
         }
     }
]);
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "created_at" : ISODate("2014-06-03T02:51:42.000Z"),
            "date_minus_3" : ISODate("2014-06-02T23:51:42.000Z"),
            "hour_from_original" : 2,
            "hour_from_date_minus_3" : 23
        }, 
        {
            "created_at" : ISODate("2014-06-04T11:23:17.000Z"),
            "date_minus_3" : ISODate("2014-06-04T08:23:17.000Z"),
            "hour_from_original" : 11,
            "hour_from_date_minus_3" : 8
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```